# Cut data to another sheet when archive row 5th vba code

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a small project to move data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 when row of sheet 1 is greater than 5.

For ex:

Sheet 1 have data like this:

[image]

and sheet 2 have data like this:

[image]

When Row 6th or greater than of sheet 1 have data. It will move data from row 6th of sheet 1 to first row of sheet 2.

Something like this:
When row 6 of sheet 1 have data (Data is 999 at row 6th):

[image]

It will cut 999 to sheet 2 at first row:

[image]

I tried this with SheetChange event. And here is my code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WS1 As Excel.Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Excel.Worksheet
Set WS1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set WS2 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")

MaxRow = 5

'find last row of sheet 1 and sheet 2
WS1LastRow = WS1.Cells(WS1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
WS2LastRow = WS2.Cells(WS2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

If (Target.Row > MaxRow) Then
    NumberOfRowGreater5 = WS1LastRow - MaxRow
    'move data of sheet 2 down
    WS2.Range("A" & 2 + NumberOfRowGreater5 & ":" & "A" & WS2LastRow + NumberOfRowGreater5).Value = WS2.Range("A2:A" & WS2LastRow).Value
    WS2.Range("A2:A" & 2 + NumberOfRowGreater5 - 1).Clear

    'Cut data from row 5th of sheet 1 to sheet 2
     WS2.Range("A2:A" & 2 + NumberOfRowGreater5 - 1).Value = WS1.Range("A" & MaxRow + 1 & ":" & "A" & WS1LastRow).Value
     WS1.Range("A" & MaxRow + 1 & ":" & "A" & WS1LastRow).Clear
End If
```

End Sub

But sometime it move data wrong, sometime it duplicate data, sometime it lost data. I don't know whether is there any way better to move data without duplicated or lost data. I consider with Range.Cut function of vba but it the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this commented code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MaxRow As Long, ws1LastRow As Long, NumberOfRowGreater5 As Long
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet

    Set WS2 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")
    MaxRow = 5

    ws1LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row 'find column A last not empty row of current sheet (you're in its own change event handler!)
    If (ws1LastRow > MaxRow) Then '<--| if some values beyond column A row 5
        NumberOfRowGreater5 = ws1LastRow - MaxRow '<--| store rows number to be taken off current sheet and inserted in "Ssheet2"
        Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events not to trigger this event handele in a possibly infinite loop
        On Error GoTo exitsub '<--| be sure to exit this sub properly
        With WS2 '<--| reference "Sheet2"
            With .Range("A2", .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A cells from row2 down to last not empty one
                .Offset(NumberOfRowGreater5).Value = .Value '<--| shift values down 'NumberOfRowGreater5' rows
            End With
        End With
        With Range("A6").Resize(NumberOfRowGreater5) '<--| reference current sheeet column A range to be "shifted" (i.e. from row 6 down to last not empty one)
            WS2.Range("A2").Resize(NumberOfRowGreater5).Value = .Value '<--| copy its values to "Sheet2" range from row 2 down 'NumberOfRowGreater5' rows
            .ClearContents '<--| clear its content . Here you'd trigger Worksheet_Change() event again hadn't you disabled events
        End With
exitsub:
        Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| enable events back
    End If
End Sub
```

actually, you could avoid the `Application.EnableEvents` setting and consequent error handling since at `Worksheet_Change()` 2nd firing after `.ClearContents` statement the `If (ws1LastRow > MaxRow) Then` check would return `False`

but keep it as a good coding practice habit

Comment: Wow, It' look wonderful than what I expected. Thanh you so much